# In the last sector 'The last stand', how to identify potential rebels location takeover?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

Is there a way to know the rebels location takeover progress, and estimate how many turns the will take a location?

**REMARK** - I don't mean the usual 'rebels will takeover in the next turn'!

[image]

Comment: So, you are asking what determines the order of locations taken over by the rebel fleet? Other than those taken over as the flagship passes, I think it's random; the best you get is a one turn warning that a location is under attack so you can avoid jumping into an (extra-)hostile situation.

Comment: Take a closer look at the picture, some locations are yellow, some more red, maybe there is something in it, like redder are next?

Comment: The ones that are "more red" are wherever the red warning stripes that cross the whole sector are. They don't seem to mean anything beyond "There are transparent red stripes placed above us, so we appear more red".

Comment: mmm, I'll check it out over some turns...

Comment: @Trent - can you post, so I'll mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing round-1 picture (on the left) with the last round picture, found no change in the locations (that are not rebel-controlled) - no visual change to indicate rebel take over status / warning.

After careful check - taking over a location, with 'possible ship', doesn't prevent the rebels to take-over that location. This negates the idea that it might affect the rebels progress.

[image]

Comment: I've just got another idea - if there is no ship in a location ==> the rebels can't take over?!